# Prevent redundant resuts in SQL query

Tags: sql

My query to find time clash works like this -

```
create table dat(id int, s time(7), e time(7));

insert into dat (id,s,e) values(1,'16:00:00.0000000','18:00:00.0000000')
insert into dat (id,s,e) values(2,'15:00:00.0000000','17:00:00.0000000')
insert into dat (id,s,e) values(3,'12:00:00.0000000','15:00:00.0000000')

//data part

QUERY - 

select * from dat a, dat b

 where  a.id != b.id 

and a.s < b.e and a.e > b.s
```

Result - 
[image]

Now the problem is that the query lists - 
 in the first row, that id 1 conflicts with id 2

and in the second row, id 2 conflicts back with id 1.

I need the distinct of this query. Please suggest.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Although I can't help with MSSQL specific functions, you might achieve good results by `group by`ing on `a.id` and `array_agg`ing `b.id`. Like this you have the a all overlapping `b` for each `a` and no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * from dat a, dat b 
WHERE a.id < b.id 
    AND a.s < b.e 
    AND a.e > b.s
```

You can avoid the duplicate pairs by setting first id to be lower than second id.

Comment: thanks it works here..though i dont know if it will work in my original scenario..thanks anyways